# Is my wife an eligible student for the American Opportunity Tax Credit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california

My wife took 2 courses in a community college in California. She completed one semester and then did not continue. I paid for her fees. (All of her previous education was completed in India.) She received a 1098-T from the college.

Is she a eligible student for the AOTC credit?

Comment: Did you read [the criteria](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/aotc) listed by the IRS?  The information you provided is fairly limited, and makes me wonder, for instance: a) was your wife pursuing a degree?; had your wife previously completed four years of higher education?; does your wife have a SSN or TIN?

Comment: I did go through the criteria, but did not quiet understand it. So, she intended to pursue an Associates degree but did not end up completing it. All of her previous education was done in India and she does not yet have a SSN or ITIN. We are applying for her ITIN with the 0017 taxes.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt she qualifies for the AOTC.  Two courses in a semester likely does not qualify her as "[enrolled at least half time](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/aotc)."  You can look at the 1098-T to whether the school checked Box 8.  I would guess that she does not qualify in other ways as well (such as "pursuing a degree").

However, your wife may qualify for the [Lifetime Learning Credit](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/lifetime-learning-credit).  This will depend on your personal tax situation.  Additionally, California (or your home state if you don't live in California) may have its own education credits/deductions that could apply to you.